# Is the Taylor expansion of $e^{x}$ an eigenvector of the differential operator on $\mathcal{P}_{n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Wouldn't this be an eigenvector of the differential operator on $\mathcal{P}_{n}$?

$$e^{x} = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} \ldots $$

(corresponding with the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$)

I read (in Halmos's Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces) that the only eigenvector of $D$ on $\mathcal{P}_{n}$ is $x=1$ with eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$. I'm wondering how that can be true.

Comment: If $\mathcal P_n$ is a space of _polynomials_, then those are only allowed to have _finite degree_.

Comment: Oh.... That was a silly oversight. Thank you. How about $P$, the infinite-dimensional vector space? Is the expansion of $e^x$ then an eigenvector?

Comment: If you're allowed to have series of infinite degree, then yes, $e^x$ is an eigenvector. Note, however, that the conventional "space of all polynomials", while infinite-dimensional, does not allow any infinite-degree series, only polynomials of _any finite_ degree.

Comment: $P$ is infinite dimensional even if we allow polynomials of arbitrarily high **finite** degree.

Comment: Okay, but then didn't you just say $e^x$ is an eigenvector of the space of all polynomials? So if $P_{\infty}$ only allows polynomials of finite degree, it wouldn't allow the expansion of $e^x$ would it?